# Recommendations for Cerf theory?

Tags: book-recommendation, morse-theory

Are there any good references for Cerf theory, written in English? The main references I see are usually Cerf's own papers in French. In particular, I am looking for a source developing the fundamental result that any 1-parameter family of functions between two Morse functions can be approximated by a family which is Morse at all but finitely many degenerate times, along with the classification (seen on wikipedia for example) of these degenerate points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe **A. E. Hatcher** and **J. B. Wagoner**, *Pseudo-isotopies of compact manifold*, Astérisque, vol. 6. (1973) is self-contained and goes beyond what Cerf proved in **J. Cerf**, *La stratification naturelle de functions différentiables réelles et le théorème de la pseudo-isotopie*, Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Etud. Sci., vol. 39 (1970), pp. 5-173.